# Robots.txt как правильно оформить?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Задача следующая, сайт имеет ЧПУ и у него все ссылки если не каталог то .html но есть одна и фильтры типа такого: **/news/?news_tags=%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE**
И есть постраничная навигация типа **/news/?news_start=40**
Как мне закрыть от роботов все, что идет после **?** но оставить **news_start**?

Это я на примере новостей сделал но вообще у меня есть статьи и справочник.

Да почему спрашиваю. Я когда-то поставил **Disallow: /*?** а сейчас мне надо именно открыть новости, переделывать тип постраничной навигации не хочу. Хочу разобраться на данном примере с robots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Disallow: /news/?news_tags=*
Disallow: /news/?news_feeds=*
```

... и т.д. со всеми возможными параметрами, кроме /news/?news_start

Comment: т.е. никаких последовательностей таких как 
**Disallow: /*?**
**Allow: /?*news_start**
не сработает?

Comment: Директива Allow понимают не все краулеры. Хотя краулеры основных поисковиков понимают. Пробуйте.

Comment: Меня интересует в данном случаи только гугл и яндекс там сработает?

Comment: Да. Вот инструкция Яндекса по robots.txt http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=996567&ncrnd=1385